# How to echo every after 9th iteration of a loop? First echo only counted 8 items

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, modulus

My code is below:

```
function portfolio_gallery() {
    global $conn;   
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT codename, namegroup, features, title, showimage FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC");

    if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        echo '<div>';
        $i = 0; 
        while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
            $i++;
            if ($row["showimage"]) {

               if($i % 9 == 0){
                     echo '</div><div>';
            }

              echo '<a class="imgpop" href="images/portfolio/large/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" rel="'.$row["namegroup"].'" title="'.$row["title"].' - '.$row["features"].'"><img src="images/portfolio/thumb/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" alt="'.$row["title"].'" width="348"/><span class="imgpop-caption">'.$row["title"].'</span></a>';
              }

        }
        echo '</div>';
    }
}

portfolio_gallery();
```

I wanted to echo `</div><div>` for every after 9th item of the loop but every time I executed the code, the **first** echo only happened after 8 items instead of 9, but the rest was every 9th.

Comment: remove `$i++;` and `if($i++ % 9 == 0){`

Comment: write `$i++;` at the end of while loop

Comment: Move the `echo` up to before the `if($i % 9 == 0){...}`...

Comment: declare $i = 1 instead of 0; and write $i++ at the end of while loop.

Comment: By the way, you should move the `showimage` condition to your sql; there is no point in getting rows you are not going to use anyway.

Comment: @jeroen I forgot about that.. though it didn't solve the problem, but you're right. I changed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by modifying the condition:

So instead of: `if($i % 9 == 0) {...}`

I used: `if($i!=0 && $i % 9 == 0) {...}`

And also placing `$i++` at the end of while loop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to increment

```
$i
```

after

```
if($i % 9 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

declare $i = 1 and Write $i++ at the end of while loop.

```
if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo '<div>';
    $i = 1; // declare $i = 1 here
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {

        if ($row["showimage"]) {
           if($i % 9 == 1){ // 10 , 19 ,28
                 echo '</div><div>';
           }
           echo '<a class="imgpop" href="images/portfolio/large/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" rel="'.$row["namegroup"].'" title="'.$row["title"].' - '.$row["features"].'"><img src="images/portfolio/thumb/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" alt="'.$row["title"].'" width="348"/><span class="imgpop-caption">'.$row["title"].'</span></a>';
        }
        $i++; // increment at end of the loop
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: I did this and it counted every 9th, except for the first which echoed after no items, like so:`<div></div><div>`

Answer (score 0):

follow the syntax example i worked out its working

```
    <?php
    $j=0; 
    for($i=0;$i<=50;$i++)
    {
        if($j==9)
        {

            echo $j.'hioiiiiiii<br/>';  //echo "</div><div>";
         $j=-1; 
        }
       $j++;
    }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :)

```
<?php 
 function portfolio_gallery() {
    global $conn;   
    $query = $conn->query("SELECT codename, namegroup, features, title, showimage FROM portfolio ORDER BY id DESC");

if ($query->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    echo '<div>';
    $i = 0;
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row["showimage"]) {

           if($i % 9 == 0){
                echo '</div><div>';
            }

            echo '<a class="imgpop" href="images/portfolio/large/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" rel="'.$row["namegroup"].'" title="'.$row["title"].' - '.$row["features"].'"><img src="images/portfolio/thumb/'.$row["codename"].'.jpg" alt="'.$row["title"].'" width="348"/><span class="imgpop-caption">'.$row["title"].'</span></a>';
        }
    $i++;
    }
    echo '</div>';
}
```

}

Comment: I tried this but the first echo returned after 4 items.